# Django: How to filter Users that belong to a specific group

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to narrow a query set for a form field that has a foreignkey to the User's table down to the group that a user belongs to.

The groups have been previously associated by me. The model might have something like the following:

```
myuser = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

And my ModelForm is very bare bones:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

So when I instantiate the form I do something like this in my views.py:

```
form = MyForm()
```

Now my question is, how can I take the myuser field, and filter it so only users of group 'foo' show up.. something like:

```
form.fields["myuser"].queryset = ???
```

The query in SQL looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * from auth_user INNER JOIN auth_user_groups ON auth_user.id = auth_user_groups.user_id INNER JOIN auth_group ON auth_group.id = auth_user_groups.group_id WHERE auth_group.name = 'client';
```

I'd like to avoid using raw SQL though. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You'll want to use [Django's convention for joining across relationships](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to join to the group table in your query set.

Firstly, I recommend giving your relationship a `related_name`.  This makes the code more readable than what Django generates by default.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    myuser = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='groups')
```

If you want only a single group, you can join across that relationship and compare the name field using either of these methods:

```
form.fields['myuser'].queryset = User.objects.filter(
    groups__name='foo')
form.fields['myuser'].queryset = User.objects.filter(
    groups__name__in=['foo'])
```

If you want to qualify multiple groups, use the `in` clause:

```
form.fields['myuser'].queryset = User.objects.filter(
    groups__name__in=['foo', 'bar'])
```

If you want to quickly see the generated SQL, you can do this:

```
qs = User.objects.filter(groups__name='foo')
print qs.query
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Joe. I posted the SQL for this above right as you posted the answer. Appreciate the feedback, works excellent.

Comment: No prob, I went back and edited it to show you how to print out the SQL for a query set so you can compare it to what you're expecting.

Answer (score 31):

This is a really old question, but for those googling the answer to this (like I did), please know that the accepted answer is no longer 100% correct. A user can belong to multiple groups, so to correctly check if a user is in some group, you should do:

```
qs = User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=['foo'])
```

Of course, if you want to check for multiple groups, you can add those to the list:

```
qs = User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=['foo', 'bar'])
```

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your concern about qualifying multiple groups, but there's nothing wrong with using '=' as opposed to 'in' if you are trying to limit to a single group.

Comment: Seconding @JoeHolloway here. The `User.objects.filter(groups__name='foo')` format works perfectly fine when querying for users in a single group.