# Django. Filter users by permissions / groups

Tags: python, html, django, web

Programming experts, hello! ;) I am a newbie in django programming and i can't find any relevant information about how to get a list of users by their permissions. I have spend literally like two hours looking all over the web and there are a lot of similar questions, but none of them is understandable how to use.

What i need is to get a list of users with admin permissions in my html template and show it in the panel.

I have just started with django a week ago and I seriously struggle to understand what goes where. Following best answer from a [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810891/django-how-to-filter-users-that-belong-to-a-specific-group) i do understand that:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    myuser = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='groups')
```

goes to my models.py, but i cant really get where would i have to put

```
form.fields['myuser'].queryset = User.objects.filter(groups__name='foo')
form.fields['myuser'].queryset = User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=['foo'])
```

code to... :/

I also have tried another solution (from the same source as above)

```
qs = User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=['foo'])
```

to put it in my model.py, such as:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    qs = User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=['Administrators'])
```

but when i do "makemigrations" i get a lot of errors.

Thank you in advance for understanding

Comment: The one of best starting resources would probably be Django documentation starting with intro to help you out with file structure and relevant info  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

Regarding your question, there is a lot wrong in your question, from indentation of your code to having queryset in model which is not a place for it. Also it would be wise to include error-stack to help you out.

Comment: can you post the errors

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter not only by user's permission but also by group's permission for those to which a user belongs.

A sort of:

```
perm = Permission.objects.get(codename='...')
User.objects.filter(Q(groups__permissions=perm) | Q(user_permissions=perm)).distinct()
```