# django Filter customers in the specific user groups

Tags: django, usergroups

I want to display Customers from specific groups in the ListView, not able to understand how to get the queryset

```
class CustomerList(ListView):
  model = Customer
  queryset = Customer.objects.filter(member__groups__name__in=['online', 'whatsapp'])
  template_name = 'customer/customer_list.html'
```

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model): 
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_("Customer"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, verbose_name=_("Contact"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Customers are added to the groups as below:

```
class AddUser(CreateView):
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     form = UserForm(request.POST) 
     if form.is_valid(): 
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='online')
        user.groups.add(group)
        user.save()
```

Comment: `__in` requires two flat dashes instead of one, does that fix it?

Comment: @voodoo-burger - sorry typo there, but it did not work as well

Comment: The use of `related_name` is confusing here. What if you remove it, run migrations and use `user__groups__name__in`?

Comment: @voodoo-burger - let me try that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: How to filter Users that belong to a specific group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810891/django-how-to-filter-users-that-belong-to-a-specific-group)

Comment: @voodoo-burger -  already tried but no luck! That `queryset` only returns users whereas I want entire Customer object as there are certain other fields of the `Customer` model to be displayed on the template

Comment: Uhm, if you are using this inside `Customer.objects.filter()` it can only return `Customer` objects... If you need more info about the user linked to the customer you can get it with `object.customer.x`. It's extremely confusing that you give your `Customer` model a field that is also named `customer`.

Comment: ok let me change it to resolve ur confustion

Comment: What is the result of `print(Customer.objects.filter(member__groups__name__in=['online', 'whatsapp']).count())`?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu - Its zero (0). but I am sure that there are customers with `online` groups. and its not misspelled too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have similar code working, check if this works for you -

```
class ProfessorsList(generic.list.ListView):
  model = Staff
  queryset = Staff.objects.filter(member__groups__name='teaching')
```

For multiple groups, you would do as: (I believe you're already doing it...)

```
Customer.objects.filter(member__groups__name__in=['online', ...])
```

If it still does not work for you try like this:

```
  users = User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=[your_groups])
  queryset = Customer.objects.filter(member__in=users)
```

Make sure `customers` have `users` and `users` are part of `your_groups`